# difference between "DataOutputStream" and "ObjectOutputStream"

Tags: java, io

I'm a beginner programmer following this [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

In the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) section, two of the classes mentioned are [Data Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) and [Object Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html).

They are used very similarily:

```
out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));

// ..

in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile)));
```

for `DataInputStream` and

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));

// ..

in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile)));
```

for `ObjectInputStream`

I know it says that `DataInputStreams` are used for primitive objects, and `ObjectInputStreams` are used for objects (and serialization of them), so which one should I use? It isn't a noticeable difference between the two example classes which both use primitive types. I usually use primitive types, too.

For performance, which one is better? and are there any other large differences?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataStreams` are used for I/O of *primitive types* which are `int`, `float`, `double` and so on.

`ObjectStreams` are used for I/O of *objects*.

If you know you're going to be explicitly working with primitive types then use `DataStreams`, otherwise go with the more generic `ObjectStreams` which implement the [DataInput interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) as well as [ObjectInput interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInput.html) so can work with primitives as well as objects.